# there is no bin folder, when I create a Dart project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: dart, bin

When I create a Dart project in Intellij IDEA, I can't find a bin folder? that's why huh?
Previously I chose "Simple console Application - a simple command-line application" from Generate sample content: ..Please help, friends.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't find the bin folder when i created dart project in vscode.But then, i realized that when you go to the actual folder location, the bin folder exist.Hence i opened the dart file inside it simply by right clicking and opening with VsCode.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the project name which starts with lowercase letter it will create the necessary folders apparently.